# Change Header Image on Blog Post for Mobile View

Tags: css, blog, mobile, responsive

I need to use a different header image for a specific blog post.
https://staging3.ryanlawn.com/blog/ryan-lawn-tree-named-to-the-great-game-of-business-2021-all-star-team/

I have tried different CSS variations, but to no avail.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .post-id-41012 .page-banner bg {
    background-image: url('https://staging3.ryanlawn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ggob-blog-banner-all-star-2021-m.jpg') !important;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the class correctly. The container has both the `page-banner` and the `bg` classes, so you should write it like this: `.page-banner.bg`

And the class `post-id-41012` doesn't exist in your document. `postid-41012` does.

So try this way:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .postid-41012 .page-banner.bg {
    background-image: url('https://staging3.ryanlawn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ggob-blog-banner-all-star-2021-m.jpg') !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great!